# if node not found in binary search tree

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, binary-search-tree, computer-science

guys what I should write in number of comparison for 62 ? i am so confused
[image]

Comment: I think the answer should be 7. Let's start - 100 -> 1, 90 -> 2, 80 ->3, 50 -> 4, 65 -> 5, 60 -> 6. after this point we will try to look for 62 at the right of 60, so count will be count + 1, so 7, now we see right of 60 is null, thus returning from function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, when searching for 62 you end up at node 60, finding its value is not equal to 62 (which is the 6th comparison) and can't continue ... so the answer is 6.

Comment: sure 6?  cuz based on the law ( number of comparison= internal path length+1) @Gregor Ophey

Comment: That law only holds for values that are actually in the tree. Otherwise there is no path.

Comment: okay Gregor i think the same and i'll tell u what i got later

Comment: @Judy so, what did you get?

Comment: @Judy Awesome! You could help me, too, by accepting my answer... just hit that check mark below the votes next to the answer, thx!